# How can I properly clone a JQM listview?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a page with a JQM listview as the main content. Then another page is navigated to that needs to use that same listview as a sidebar. My first thought was to use clone() to properly clone the list onto the other page.

This works really well if the first page (<s>example removed</s>) has already been loaded. However, if the user navigates directly to the second page (<s>example removed</s>), when it clones the list, it hasn't been initialized by JQM as a listview, so it doesn't display correctly.  I can't figure out how to get this to initialize/clone correctly.

The site in question is <s>example removed</s>.

If my problem isn't clear let me know, and I'll try to clear it up a bit.

Comment: Call `.trigger('create')` on the page to initialize all of it's child elements. You could also instead select the ul directly and call `.listview()` if it isn't initialized, or `.listview('refresh')` if it is already initialized.

Comment: @KevinB I've actually been trying all three of those without success. I'll give it a shot again and update with what I've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick with initializing the refreshing was a pain to figure out, but basically what I had to do was `try` to refresh the list I was cloning, and if this failed (exception thrown), then initialize the clone list. If it succeeded in refreshing, then it had already been initialized and I did not need to initialize the clone.

```
try {
    // try to refresh the parent, if it works, we don't need to do anything
    $('#To-Clone').listview('refresh');
} catch (e) {
    // if refreshing the parent fails, then it wasn't initialized, and we need to initialize the child
    $('#Clone').listview();
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem, but I'm not sure if it is the proper way to do it, so I'm leaving it open.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a function that builds the menu, include it on each page of your site (if you don't already have a global JS include file), and then call it to build your menu whenever necessary:

```
function build_menu($container) {
    var out = '<ul data-role="listview">...</ul>';

    $container.append(out).trigger('create');
}
$(document).delegate('#my-page-id', 'pageinit', function () {
    build_menu($(this).children('.ui-page'));
});
```

Otherwise you can check if the widget has the `.ui-listview` class which is applied during initialization.

```
//cache the clone
var $clone = $('#my-element').clone();

//check if the clone has the initialized class
if ($clone.hasClass('ui-listview')) {

    //since this listview has already been initialized, refresh it
    $('#my-container').append($clone).children().last().listview('refresh');
} else {

    //initialize this listview clone
    $('#my-container').append($clone).children().last().listview();
}
```

You will want to make sure your `listview` widget doesn't have an ID or you will want to change the ID of the clone before appending it to the DOM so your IDs are unique.